# JSF page reload without the background

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have to make a webpage with jsf and primafecas, but I don't have to much experience with it. I have to change the content of the page without reloading everything( the background is quite large).
I made a menu(with toolbar) and an iframe to easily change the content (gmap, text, forms, datatable etc). I know it is one of the worst solution, but I couldn't find better.

Now I have to change the menu from the iframe, but it looks impossible, so I'd like to use a nice method instead of the iframe. I tried a few things, but nothing worked well, sometimes i got duplicate id error or nothing worked, but sometimes nothing rendered except the menu.

Now the code looks like this:

```
<ui:define name="menu">
        <h:form id="menuForm">
            <p:toolbar activeIndex="#{navigationBean.pageCount}">
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:commandButton value="menu1" action="#{navigationBean.setUrl(...)}" update=":frmContent,menuForm" />
                    <p:commandButton  value="menu2" action="#{navigationBean.setUrl(...)}" update=":frmContent,menuForm" />
                    <p:commandButton  value="menu3" action="#{navigationBean.setUrl(...)}" update=":frmContent,menuForm" />
                    <p:commandButton  value="menu3"  action="#{navigationBean.setUrl(...)}" update=":frmContent,menuForm"/>
            </p:toolbar>

        </h:form>

</ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">

           <h:form id="frmContent" style="height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%">
                <iframe src="#{navigationBean.url}" id="frame" frameborder="0" style="height:100%;width:100%" height="100vh" width="100%"/>
       </h:form>
```

I need a working method to change the content or the whole page without the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
<ui:include src="#{navigationBean.url}" />
```

instead of the iframe.

Comment: I tried it, but the included parts didn't worked. I got duplicate id error. I fixed that, but none of the buttons work. How should I reference to the other components inside and outside f the include?

Comment: I rebuilt your solution, it seems to work for me. Maybe it is just the missing Closing Tag for "<p:toolbarGroup align="right">"? (There is no "</p:toolbarGroup>") in your Post.)

Comment: Ohh, I just forgot to copy it.

I tried it again and there was a little mistake which cause the error. Now it works, but only once. It doesn't do anything if I push the button. After reloading the page it works for 1 click, but never again.

Comment: I rewrite the template file and everything works.
Thanks for the help!